# UIPickerView doesn't spin/floats horizontally and vertically when trying to swipe it

Tags: ios

Having an issue with UIPickerView not spinning (iOS7/8), floating around left and right uncontrolled, being barely usable only when tapping on its values (and still horrible even then). It must be due to one of the library references, but I'm yet to figure out what exactly is causing it. The easiest way to reproduce it is by dropping a UIPickerView into one of the pages controlled by SLPagingView (https://github.com/StefanLage/SLPagingView) - screenshots included.
Just trying to see if anyone experienced this every with this trivial control?

[image: spinner going nuts]
[image: more]

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in one of the referenced rogue libraries that overrode some of the default behavior by extending built-in controls and data types.

After excluding them one at a time from the project, cleaning it, and rebuilding, I eventually found the culprit.